# Are there variables which are equals and not equals?

Tags: java

Can I create a and b variables that the following statement will be true?

```
    (a != b && a == b)
```

Comment: No you can't. Have you got a specific purpose?

Comment: I'm curious: to what end?

Comment: You can create variables that are not `==` but are `equals`, if this is what you meant.

Comment: I can't see how.  It might be possible to do `a != b && a.equals(b)` though

Comment: With another `Thread`, you can make this occasionally true.

Comment: No, there is no special purpose. I am just curious.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the exact expression, but something like that can be used to detect NaN.

Comment: @HotLicks: Yeah, I think I saw something like this in *Java Puzzlers*.

Comment: @Hot Licks: not in Java. http://ideone.com/WSwyAY

Comment: Maybe it's `(a != a)`, though I've also seen some other more complex version like maybe `(a >= b && a <= b)`.

Comment: You can get `(i <= j && j <= i && i != j)` to evaluate to `true`.  :)  *Java Puzzlers* "Curse Of Looper" puzzle.

Comment: From java.lang.Double:  `static public boolean isNaN(double v) {
        return (v != v);
    }`

Comment: You can also get `a == (-a)` to be true, and also `a == (a + 1)`. That's also from _Java Puzzlers_. :)

Answer (score 4):

Generally you cannot make this condition `true`, because one of the subconditions being `true` makes the other one of them is `false`, making the overall expression `false`.

But it is possible for a `Thread` to make both conditions `true`, by updating the value of one of them in between evaluations.

```
public class ComparisonTest
{
   static int a = 0;
   static int b = 0;
   static int caught = 0;

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      new Thread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            while (b < 100000)
            {
               a++;
               b++;
            }
         }
      }).start();

      while (b < 100000)
      {
         if ((a != b) && (a == b))
         {
            System.out.println("Caught it! #" + (++caught));
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The thread continuously updates `a` and `b`.  The main thread continuously checks the condition.  It is possible that the updater thread is interrupted after it updates `a` but before it updates `b`.  Then the first check `a != b` is `true`.  Then the updater thread updates `b` and is interrupted again.  The main thread performs its second check, `a == b` and that's `true` also.  For me, this program caught it 82 times in 100,000 updates:

```
Caught it! #1
Caught it! #2
Caught it! #3
Caught it! #4
Caught it! #5
Caught it! #6
Caught it! #7
Caught it! #8
Caught it! #9
Caught it! #10
Caught it! #11
Caught it! #12
Caught it! #13
Caught it! #14
Caught it! #15
```

(snip)

```
Caught it! #80
Caught it! #81
Caught it! #82
```

Comment: Nice!  Demoed and everything.

Answer (score 3):

In multi-thread environment some variables could have different values while performing `a != b` and then change values to equal ones before `a==b`.

But I am not sure if this kind of answer you are looking for since that would indicate synchronisation problem in such app.

Comment: That's also likely a very narrow time window if there's one at all. Does (a!=b && a==b) take more than one processor instruction? Possibly, but if so, how many? If the two are evaluated on the same clock cycle (i'm only speaking theoretically) then even that's impossible. Or is it?

Comment: Unless you had an instruction for that exact expression, which would be a pretty pointless instruction, it would have to take more than one instruction. Though, since the only way this could happen would be a race condition, I'm pretty sure the JIT would be within its right to optimize that expression to a constant `false`. rgettman's demo suggests that it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

No.   Not in any language.  I mean, you could by changing the value of one of the variables in between comparisons, but that would break so many things, it would be dumb to do.

Comment: @dnk give it dynamite to that programmer as well :)

Comment: I don't really consider changing the meaning of equals to be within the scope of the question :)  It's along the same lines as my change the value of one between comparisons, which is a hack :)

Comment: For that matter you can as well in any dialect of Lisp.  Scala as well.

Comment: Basically any language that lets you overload the `==` and `!=` operators.

Answer (score 0):

this is a logical impossibility.

Interestingly enough, in C++, you technically could, since C++ allows for operator overloading (you can redefine the meaning of != and ==)

Something can not be equal and unequal at the same time, so no, not in normal code nor in the real world.

If anyone cares, there are a few other languages that can too, such as SQL and Haskell.

Comment: I know. i was going to keep it basic.

Comment: In Java, the only possibility that this may happen is that the variables are shared among two or more threads and the change of value of them is not synchronized, so there's a slightly possibility that this may occur. Of course, it will be better find the person who did this for causing so much PITA for this kind of problem :P

Answer (score 0):

Well, `a != b && a.equals(b)` is possible. But No, `a !=b && a==b` is not possible to be `true`.

as:

```
true & false = false
false & true = false
```

However,

```
String a = "asd";
String b = new String("asd"); // created just to show as example
if(a!=b && a.equals(b))
      System.out.println("duck duck"); // print duck duck
```